# Differentiable map between $\mathbb{S}^{1}$ and $\mathbb{S}^{1}\times \mathbb{S}^{1}$ and closed curve

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I'm asked to show that the map
\begin{align}
\eta\colon \mathbb{S}^{1} &\to \mathbb{S}^{1}\times \mathbb{S}^{1}\\
p&\mapsto (p,p)
\end{align}
is differentiable and also **how it is related to a closed curve**. I've shown the differentiability as follows: take the charts $\varphi\colon U\subseteq \mathbb{S}^{1} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\overline{\varphi}\colon \mathbb{S}^{1}\times \mathbb{S}^{1}\to \mathbb{R}^2$ and note that
$$
(\overline{\varphi}\circ\eta\circ\varphi^{-1})(x) = (x,x),
$$
since $\overline{\varphi}(x,y) = (\varphi(x),\varphi(y))$. Thus, the map is differentiable from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\eta$ is differentiable. My problem is with the relation of $\eta$ with a closed curve, is it the transition map? I don't quite understand what I have to prove.

Comment: This is not your main question, but note that you need at least $2$ charts to cover $S^1$ (if not, then $S^1$ would be diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$). To check differentiability, you have to see what happens in each chart.

Comment: Just to add to what Charles said, you have not defined either $\varphi$ or $\overline{\varphi}$, so it's not clear whether $\overline{\varphi}(x,y)=(\varphi(x), \varphi(y))$ or not.

Comment: It's not clear what they want when they ask "How it is related to a closed curve".

Comment: What precisely is $\overline \varphi$? Whatever it is, it can't be defined on $S^1 \times S^1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof of differentiability is a bit imprecise, but has the right idea. You need the following well-known lemma:

A map $f : M \to N$ between differentiable manifolds $M, N$ is differentiable iff for each $p \in M$ there exist charts $\varphi: U \to U' \subset \mathbb R^m$ on $M$ and $\psi : V \to V' \subset \mathbb R^n$ on $N$ such that $p \in U, f(U) \subset V$ and $\psi \circ f \circ \varphi^{-1} :  U' \to V'$ is differentiable.

Now consider $p \in S^1$ and any chart $\varphi: U \to U' \subset \mathbb R$ on $S^1$ such that $p \in U$.  Then $\overline \varphi =  \varphi \times  \varphi : U \times U \to U' \times U' \subset \mathbb R^2$ is a chart on $S^1 \times S^1$ such that $\eta(U) \subset  U \times U$. We have  $(\overline \varphi \circ \eta \circ \varphi^{-1})(x) = \overline \varphi(\eta(\varphi^{-1}(x))) =  \overline \varphi(\varphi^{-1}(x),\varphi^{-1}(x)) = (x,x)$. This shows that $\overline \varphi \circ \eta \circ \varphi^{-1}$ is differentiable.

I do not know what is your definition of a closed curve, but I guess that a valid interpretation is a map $u : [a,b] \to S^1 \times S^1$ such that $u(a) = u(b)$ and

$$\bar u : (a - (b-a), b + (b-a)) =(2a-b, 2b-a) \to S^1 \times S^1, \\ \bar u(t) = \begin{cases} u(t +(b-a) & t \in (a - (b-a),a] \\ u(t) & t \in [a,b] \\ u(t -(b-a) & t \in [b, b + (b-a)) \end{cases}$$
is differentiable.

Using the differentiable map $p : \mathbb R \to S^1, p(t) = e^{it} = \cos t + i \sin t$, we get a closed curve $u = \eta \circ p \mid_{[0,2\pi]}$.

Answer (score 0):

If you think of the torus as the unit square with opposite sides identified (or as $\Bbb R^2/\Bbb Z^2$, which amounts to the same thing), then the image $\eta(S^1)$ is the closed curve corresponding to the diagonal in the unit square (from the origin to $(1,1)$).

In terms of the fundamental group, if we identify $\pi_1(T^2)=\pi_1(S^1)×\pi_1(S^1)$, the curve would be $(\alpha(p),\alpha (p))$,  where $\alpha \in\pi_1(S^1)$ is the generator (the identity) $\alpha: S^1\to S^1$ by $\alpha(z)=z$.